# Add another email address in send mail as

Tags: java, gmail-api

i want to add another email address in send mail as section using the google gmail api. i tried this code, can anyone help me please?

```java
SendAs primaryAlias = null;
ListSendAsResponse aliases = service.users().settings().sendAs().list("me").execute();
for (SendAs alias: aliases.getSendAs()) {
   if (alias.getIsPrimary()) {
       primaryAlias = alias;
           break;
   }
}
System.out.println("Updated signature for " + primaryAlias.getDisplayName());
SendAs aliasSettings = new SendAs().setSignature("I heart cats.")
   .setSendAsEmail("j.ohnast.baby@gmail.com");
SendAs r = service.users().settings().sendAs().create("me", aliasSettings).execute();
System.out.println("Updated signature for " + r.getDisplayName());
```

---

Exception in thread "main"

```java
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority"
}
```

Comment: Is `j.ohnast.baby@gmail.com` your legimite alias that you set-up from the Gmail UI?

Comment: @ziganotschka no it is the alias that i want to create.

Answer (score 0):

Alias can be created with `Users.settings.sendAs: create` only by a service account with  domain-wide authority, as can be withdrawn from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/create).

See [here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/service-account) how to create a service account. You would need to create creadentials and store them on your drive e.g. as a `.p12` file.

Here is a sample how to set up a service account in Java:

```
public class ServiceAccountJava

 {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "XXX";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(XXX);
    public static void main(String... args)   throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();                           
     File pk12=new File("XXX.p12");     
     String serviceAccount="XXX@XXX-XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com";   
//  Builder necessary for the ability to refresh tokens
     GoogleCredential getCredentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(pk12) //RESOURCES_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON, SRC_RESOURCES_KEY_P12
      .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
      .setServiceAccountUser("XXX") //the user whom you want to impersonate
      .build();
       ...
    }
}
```